# What can I do to optimise this MariaDB query?

Tags: mariadb

The query has been anonymised for sharing on this site; the comparative example is that we are a book seller who needs to cross-reference new books, against an archive of ALL books and identify category matches. Individually, each of the following queries returns the correct data, but the sheer volume of data being handled, results in an extremely slow query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE warehouse.tmp_newBooks
(INDEX rowID (_rowid), INDEX joinIdx (publisherID, storePostcode, authorName, publisherReference, bookTitle)) AS
SELECT
    d._rowid,
    d.linkID,
    cs.publisherID,
    d.publisherReference,
    d._createdDate,
    d.authorName,
    d.address,
    d.storePostcode,
    d.bookTitle
FROM library.books d
JOIN library.publishers cs ON d.publishersID = cs._rowid
WHERE DATE(d._createdDate) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY))
     AND d.available = 'Y'
    AND d.linkID IS NULL;
    
    
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE warehouse.tmp_allBooks
(INDEX rowID (_rowid), INDEX joinIdx (publisherID, storePostcode, authorName, publisherReference, bookTitle)) AS
SELECT
    d._rowid,
    d.linkID,
    cs.publisherID,
    d.publisherReference,
    d._createdDate,
    d.authorName,
    d.address,
    d.storePostcode,
    d.bookTitle
FROM library.books d
JOIN library.publishers cs ON d.publishersID = cs._rowid;

SELECT 
    d._rowid,
    d.linkID,
    case 
        when d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle AND IFNULL(d.storePostcode,'') <> IFNULL(dd.storePostcode,'') AND d.authorName = dd.authorName then 'CATEGORY A'
        when d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference AND IFNULL(d.storePostcode,'') <> IFNULL(dd.storePostcode,'') AND d.authorName <> dd.authorName  then 'CATEGORY B'
        WHEN d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName AND d.publisherReference <> dd.publisherReference then 'CATEGORY C'
        when d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName AND d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference AND d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle then 'CATEGORY D'
        when d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName AND d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference AND d.bookTitle <> dd.bookTitle then 'CATEGORY E'
        WHEN d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName AND d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference then 'CATEGORY F'
        when d.authorName = dd.authorName AND d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference  then 'CATEGORY G'
        when d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference AND d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName <> dd.authorName  then 'CATEGORY H'
        when d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference AND d.storePostcode <> dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName <> dd.authorName  then 'CATEGORY I'
        when d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle AND d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName <> dd.authorName then 'CATEGORY J'
        when d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle AND d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode then 'CATEGORY K'
        when d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle AND d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName then 'CATEGORY L'
        when d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle AND d.authorName = dd.authorName AND d.storePostcode <> dd.storePostcode then 'CATEGORY M'
        when d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle AND d.authorName <> dd.authorName AND d.storePostcode <> dd.storePostcode then 'CATEGORY N'
        END AS 'Result'
FROM warehouse.tmp_allBooks dd 
LEFT JOIN warehouse.tmp_newBooks d ON
    d._rowid <> dd._rowid AND
    d.publisherID = dd.publisherID AND
   ((d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName) or d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference OR d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle)
GROUP BY d._rowid;
```

tmp_newBooks contains 626 rows
tmp_allBooks contains 44,697 rows when limited for testing
the select query takes 15 minutes to run, if it doesn't crash

In the production environment, tmp_allBooks would contain a little over 4 million rows

An explain on the last query has

| select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIMPLE | dd | ALL | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | 44424 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| SIMPLE | d | ref | joinIdx | joinIdx | 5 | warehouse.dd.branchID | 1 | Using where |

Answer (score 1):

This is **not Sargable**;

```
DATE(d._createdDate) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```

change to

```
d._createdDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

**Index**:

```
library:  INDEX(available, link_id, _createdDate)
```

Are you sure about **`LEFT`**?

```
LEFT JOIN warehouse.tmp_newBooks d ON
    d._rowid <> dd._rowid AND ...
GROUP BY d._rowid
```

When the `LEFT JOIN` does not find a matching row in the "right" table (`d`), it will deliver all `NULLs` for those columns.  Was that intentional?  Or did you need a plain `JOIN`?

And the `GROUP BY` will have a row with `NULL` for `_rowid`; are you expecting that?

And, I think, the `CASE` will be `NULL`.

**Not clear**:

```
SELECT ..., cs.publisherID, ...
    ...
    WHERE d.publishersID = cs._rowid
```

Recommend being consistent on "row" versus "publisher".  (And maybe this inconsistency is leading to unnecessary sluggishness?

Once the above is resolve, *maybe* you can **avoid** the `TEMPORARY TABLEs` and simply `JOIN` to `publisher` in the final `SELECT`.

`key=joinIdx` and `key_len=5` probably implies that only the first column of that index was being used.

**`OR`** is hard to optimize.  A *possible* optimization for

```
  (d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName)
or d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference
OR d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle
order by  `group_wallets_transactions`.`created_at` desc
```

is to use `UNION DISTINCT`:

```
( SELECT ...
     WHERE (d.storePostcode = dd.storePostcode AND d.authorName = dd.authorName)
) UNION DISTINCT (
( SELECT ...
     WHERE d.publisherReference = dd.publisherReference
) UNION DISTINCT (
( SELECT ...
     WHERE d.bookTitle = dd.bookTitle
)
order by  `group_wallets_transactions`.`created_at` desc
```